# SQL Query Using IN. I want to Convert query in EXISTS

Tags: database

```
SELECT 
    lpn.TC_LPN_ID 
FROM LPN lpn 
WHERE lpn.inbound_Outbound_Indicator = 'O' 
    AND lpn.tc_company_id = 1403 
    AND lpn.TC_REFERENCE_LPN_ID **IN**  
        (SELECT 
            l.tc_lpn_id 
         FROM lpn l 
         WHERE l.TC_COMPANY_ID = 1403 
             AND l.inbound_Outbound_Indicator = 'I' 
             AND (l.tc_lpn_id= '000990950' OR l.TC_REFERENCE_LPN_ID = '000990950'))
```

Want to modify my query to **EXISTS**.

**EXISTS** improve performance.

Comment: Are you sure EXISTS improves performance? Usually I avoid it like the plague

Comment: IMO it depends on engine. In MS Access, In() conditions sometimes are much slower than Exists() ones. In MS SQL query optimizer usually creates same execution plan (if statements are otherwise equal).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lpn.tc_lpn_id
  FROM lpn lpn
 WHERE lpn.inbound_outbound_indicator = 'O'
   AND lpn.tc_company_id = 1403
   AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM lpn l
           WHERE lpn.tc_reference_lpn_id = l.tc_lpn_id
             AND l.tc_company_id = 1403
             AND l.inbound_outbound_indicator = 'I'
             AND (   l.tc_lpn_id = '000990950'
                  OR l.tc_reference_lpn_id = '000990950'
                 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN improves performance more.

You can express your query as a standard inner join to itself:

```
SELECT 
    lpn.TC_LPN_ID 
FROM LPN
JOIN lpn l
    ON l.TC_COMPANY_ID = lpn.l.TC_COMPANY_ID
    AND l.tc_lpn_id = lpn.TC_REFERENCE_LPN_ID
    AND l.inbound_Outbound_Indicator = 'I'
    AND l.tc_lpn_id = '000990950' OR l.TC_REFERENCE_LPN_ID = '000990950')
WHERE lpn.inbound_Outbound_Indicator = 'O' 
AND lpn.tc_company_id = 1403
```

Note that I removed the pointless aliasing of `lpn` to itself - ie `FROM LPN lpn` is identical to simply `FROM LPN`: aliasing a table to its own name has no effect.